# How to add custom registration fields to woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to create my own custom registration fields in woocommerce as follows
1. First name
2. Password
3. Email
4. Choose option
a. Tailor
b. Model
Users that sign up should always fill this form first.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use this plug in with a shortcode that able you to have something look like what you need
**woocommerce simple registration**
*description:*
A simple plugin to add a **[woocommerce_simple_registration]** shortcode to display the registration form on a separate page.